# Xubuntu 16.04 on VMWare throws CPU error

Tags: windows, xubuntu, vmware, cpu, windows-10

I have Xubuntu 16.04 x64 on my virtual machine. Always everything are working good but today I got an error:

[image: The CPU has been disabled]

When I enter into "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and choose this option

[image: Good option]

My machine is working fine.

How can I fix it? I don't want to go into advanced options every time when I want to run virtual machine. I'm working on Windows 10.

Images copy link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YppgX.jpg

Comment: The images cannot be shown. Please upload it tho another location, or inside the question. However, this link could help: [VMWare help](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2000542)

Comment: @GTRONICK reuploaded on imgur